# Expandable jQuery content opens when reloading

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I built in a jQuery collapsible plugin into my fixed header. (You can click the button in the right upper corner to open it)

My problem is as following, when I open the page, reload or click on a link it automatically opens for a second. I would like it stops doing that and instead only opens when someone actually clicks on the button.

I don't know which part of my code to add here so I uploaded both files.

Here is the code to the [php file](http://codepad.org/AGdvesbD)

Here is the code to the [jQuery file](http://codepad.org/kSI0lL0a)

I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I am new to this website and I just started building my own website but I'm willing to learn.

Regards

Comment: I forgot the url to my website. Here it is: [link](http://buyseoplans.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the container that holds the content to display:none in your css file to begin with.

Then when the button is clicked change the display value. You may not need to change the display value here as the jQuery which activates and shows it just now may work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response and help! It doesn't open up anymore when the page is being reloaded. Unfortunately, it doesn't open either when I click on the button. I didn't understand the second part of what you said about the button. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Where does your jQuery code for your open/close function live? What file is it in?

Comment: I think its collapse.js and collapse.min.js if I understood. There is also a php file called "collapse-o-matic".

Comment: I'd suggest just writing a simple function using jQuery toggle which shows/hides the container. Not sure if this will affect what is there already but worth a try. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Your first suggestion was correct to put display:none. I just put it in the wrong place. Thank you for your help!